# Is there any conlang that implements Reichenbach's tenses?

Tags: list-of-languages, tense-aspect-mood, engineered-languages

In [Reichenbach's theory of tense](https://aclanthology.org/W13-0107.pdf) three time points, namely the Speech time, the Event time, and the Reference time, an abstract time point from which the event is viewed, are used to classify the tenses, and this analysis introduces some new tenses compared to a traditional grammar like the Posterior Past and Posterior Future.

Is there any conlang that implements the Reichenbach tenses? If yes, which one?